# How to estimate 3D pose using 2D tracking and initial 3D pose

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, perspectivecamera

How can I calculate the 3D pose when the object is moving in the scene, I use SURF to track an object in the scene and the initial 3D pose of this object is known. All I know is once I use SURF the 2D correspondence between two consecutive frames is know, so the 3D pose should not be difficult to calculate by multiplying the original 3D poses with some transform matrix.

Comment: Cou cant compute 3D pose from 2D movement if there are no limitations in movement (e.g. movement on a 2D plane). But in psychology james gibson analyzed how image points behave when camera moves. This optical flow information might be useful.

Comment: @Micka Thanks for the reply. But how about if the initial 3D pose is known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you know the 3D location of your feature points in some fixed co-ordinate system, then upon moving your camera all you really have to do is to estimate the pose of the camera and apply the reverse transformation to know the current pose of the object in current reference frame. Such problems are known as Pn-P problems. There is a huge body of work around this, but one of the recent papers on this topic that promises an efficient algorithm to estimate pose is http://cvlabwww.epfl.ch/~lepetit/papers/lepetit_ijcv08.pdf

You can also use [cv::solvePnP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called [structure from motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_from_motion). Check the link for relevant papers and software.